# JAX-B: Compact marshalling for a Map

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

The default representation for a Map is quite verbose, e.g.:

> ```
> <fields>
>     <entry>
>         <key>
>              ...
>         </key>
>         <value>
>              ...
>         </value>
>     </entry>
> </fields>
> ```

I'd like to make it more concise, like this:

> ```
> <entry key="...">
>       ...
> </entry>
> ```

This representation assumes the key can be serialised as a String, but otherwise contains all the same information.

I realise this is possible by writing a custom converter. However, I want to do this at numerous places in my code, and writing a converter for each one would be cumbersome.

Is there a standard annotation that allows this representation? Or is there some way to have a "generic converter" that I just write once, and then attach to all the places I want to use it.